# How do i make my programmatic subviews load simultaneously with my storyboard subviews?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to setup constraints. I'm having an issue where my tableview storyboard outlet is loading before my programmatic views that i created. thus i cannot setup constraints related in between. here's my constraints...

```
func tableviewsConstraints(){
    
    //Label
    todaysdeadlineLabel = UILabel()
    todaysdeadlineLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    todaysdeadlineLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    todaysdeadlineLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    todaysdeadlineLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    todaysdeadlineLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    todaysdeadlineLabel.text = "Today's Deadlines"
    self.view.addSubview(todaysdeadlineLabel)
    
    homeTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    homeTableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    homeTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    homeTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    homeTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.todaysdeadlineLabel.topAnchor, constant: 120).isActive = true
    homeTableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: homeTableView.rowHeight * 3).isActive = true
    

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableviewsConstraints()
```

The table view is being added to the view before the label I believe.

Comment: As per your previous question, tableview is already added in the storyboard. Whatever you add further will be added above the tableview in the view hierarchy,

Comment: yes exactly how do i get around that?

Comment: @CharlesLenx - is `homeTableView` an `@IBOutlet` connected via Storyboard? If so, you should set its constraints in Storyboard, not via code. If you need to *change* them at run-time, you can also create `@IBOutlet`s for the constraints themselves, and then update their `.constant` values. And, if the table view is configured in Storyboard, why not just add the label in Storyboard as well?